Open Ball Radius, weighted Graph and shortest path
in this paper Improved Approximations for Two-stage Min-Cut and
Shortest Path Problems under Uncertainty they give an algorithm for the Two-stage Robust Shortest Path Problem. In there, they are saying:
For any $ v \in V $, $ d \in \mathbb{R}^+ $, let $ B(v, d) $ denote the open ball of radius $ d $ around $ v $, i.e.,
B(v, d) = { u $\mid$ SP(u, v) < d }.
Hence, for any $u, v \in V $, we have
$B(u, d_u) \cap B(v, d_v) = \emptyset \iff SP(u, v) \geq d_u + d_v.$
They argue using the shortest path for any point within the radius, but after trying to find an example of this usage, I came across something that seems to contradict their statement.myExample. In this example I would have and empty set as the intersection of the two open ball radii but the shortest path would be shortet than $d_1 + d_2$.
However, I'm fairly certain I’m mistaken. Could someone explain where my error lies?"
